# XSL 2.0 Associating the result of two templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Lets say I have these two templates:

```
    <xsl:template match="h1" mode="SomeMode">
        <holder><xsl:value-of select="something"/></holder>
    </xsl>
    <xsl:template match="h2" mode="SomeMode">
        <holder><xsl:value-of select="something"/></holder>
    </xsl>
```

I want the same holder to contain whatever the value-of select results in if the h1 is the preceding sibling of the h2. I already have the h1 and h2 templates and they are rather complex, but they are 'failing' to associate sibling elements.

However, I don't want to require that there be an h1 and an h2, but if there are two and h1 comes before h2, then use the same holder.  I might need slightly more complex rules as well like two h1s before an h2, etc.

My guess about how do this would be create a new template that enforces the 'h1 before h2' rule and 'call' the other templates from it.  The problem I forsee is that the h1 by itself and the h2 by itself will also match, which I don't want, plus I would need to figure out how to get the holder tags cleaned up.. ugly.

My second guess would be to look for preceding-sibling h1's in the h2 and do it that way, but again the h1 would match by itself.

Do I need a template for every possible relationship (sibling-wise) for h1 and h2?

- H1 with no siblings
- H2 with no siblings
- H1 before H2
- H1 before H1 before H2

and handle the contents this way?  I guess this is looking like the best way.

Thanks for your time.

Edit:

Here are some mode details.  I want to process tables and the preceding paragraphs, if there is a preceding paragraph.  I also need to process tables if there is no preceding p.  I also need to process p if there is no following table.  By trail and error, this seems to work, but I wonder if I should filter in match="table" like I do in match="p" (or this that somehow taken care of for me because I have two similar matches on the same type?

```
<xsl:template match="table[preceding-sibling::p]" mode="aaa">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table" mode="aaa">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="aaa">
    <xsl:variable name="sibling_table" select="following-sibling::table" />
    <xsl:if test="not($sibling_table)" >
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This seems to work, but I can't be sure yet.  It seems awkward, but if this is an acceptable way..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of searchers...

The way I finally found to accomplish this seems straightforward in hindsight, but it was tough to figure out for some reason.

Inside whatever template you are in, use apply-templates (and a mode) with a select that ORs together the types you want to associate together:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="p[node()] | list[node()] |  table[node()]" mode="SomeMode" />
```

Then create a template for each type and do whatever custom handling you have for each of them inside them:

```
    <xsl:template match="p" mode="SomeMode">
    </template>

    <xsl:template match="list" mode="SomeMode">
    </template>

     <xsl:template match="table" mode="SomeMode">
    </template>
```

This approach is then flexible enough to apply additional logic, such as requiring that p have a preceding-sibling of some type because you can add an "xsl:if" inside the template that matches p to enforce that.  Seems straightforward now.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be musing about the specification rather than telling us clearly what the rules are. Multiple template rules is certainly one way of tackling it. Another might be to use grouping, but it's hard to tell without more detail.